# What parallelism happens in a vector processor?

Tags: architecture, cpu, parallelism

From Tanebaum's Structured Computer Organization

> A vector processor is very efficient at executing a sequence of
>   operations on pairs of data elements. All of the operations are
>   performed in **a single, heavily pipelined functional unit**.   Vector
>   processors work on **arrays of data**, and execute **single
>   instructions** that, for example, add the elements together pairwise
>   for two vectors.
>
> The vector processor has the concept of **a vector register**, which
>   consists of a set of conventional registers that can be loaded from
>   memory in a single instruction, which actually **loads them from
>   memory serially**.
>
> Then a vector addition instruction performs the pairwise addition of
>   the elements of two such vectors by feeding them to **a pipelined
>   adder** from the two vector registers. The result from the adder is
>   another vector, which can either be stored into a vector register or
>   used directly as an operand for another vector operation.
>
> The SSE (Streaming SIMD Extension) instructions available on the Intel
>   Core architecture use this execution model to speed up highly regular
>   computation, such as multimedia and scientific software.

As it says, a vector processor has a single functional unit (e.g. a single adder, which seem can add a pair of scalars at one time, not a pair of vectors?), and 
the scalars in an array are loaded into a vector register from memory serially. Is there parallelism inside a vector processor?

For example, add two vectors stored as two arrays of scalars, A and B. Does it work in parallel like this:

- the adder adds a pair of scalars, A[i] and B[i], which have been stored in two vector registers,
- and at the same time, a later (j>i) pair of scalars A[j] and B[j]  are loaded from memory to the vector registers?

Or does addition take place after the two arrays A and B are completely loaded into twp vector registers? Then doesn't this make the adder idle while the scalars in each array are loaded?

Thanks.

Comment: A[i], A[i+1],A[i+2],A[i+3] are loaded into one register, B[i], B[i+1],B[i+2],B[i+3] into the other, then the add produces C[i], C[i+1],C[i+2],C[i+3].  Since the loads & stores are from consecutive memory addresses, they (generally) take the same amount of time as the load of one scalar.  The hardware can generally also do some overlapping of loads & stores.

Comment: But the book says " a set of conventional registers that can be loaded from memory in a single instruction, which actually loads them from memory serially"?